# How do Lazav, Dimir Mastermind and Vigor work together in Magic the Gathering?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say I have [Lazav, Dimir Mastermind](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Lazav%2C%20Dimir%20Mastermind) and [Vigor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=140227) on the battlefield and Vigor dies. Lazav's ability triggers and I have him become a copy of Vigor. Does he now apply Vigor's ability to himself as well, since the ability says: "other than Vigor"?

Comment: Also incidentally, noticing the way you worded the first sentence, remember Lazav would only trigger if your opponent owns the Vigor.

Answer (score 10):

Nope, when an ability on an object refers to itself by name it means "this object."

> 201.4b If an ability of an object refers to that object by name, and an object with a different name gains that ability, each instance of
>   the first name in the gained ability that refers to the first object
>   by name should be treated as the second name.
>
> Example: Quicksilver
>   Elemental says, in part, “{U}: Quicksilver Elemental gains all
>   activated abilities of target creature until end of turn.” If it gains
>   an ability that says “{G}: Regenerate Cudgel Troll,” activating that
>   ability will regenerate Quicksilver Elemental, not the Cudgel Troll it
>   gained the ability from.
>
> Example: Glacial Ray is an instant with
>   “splice onto Arcane” that says “Glacial Ray deals 2 damage to target
>   creature or player.” If it’s spliced onto a Kodama’s Reach, that
>   Kodama’s Reach deals 2 damage to the target creature or player.
>
> Example: Dimir Doppelganger says “{1}{U}{B}: Exile target creature
>   card from a graveyard. Dimir Doppelganger becomes a copy of that card
>   and gains this ability.” Dimir Doppelganger’s ability is activated
>   targeting a Runeclaw Bear card. The Doppelganger becomes a copy of
>   Runeclaw Bear and gains an ability that should be treated as saying
>   “{1}{U}{B}: Exile target creature card from a graveyard. Runeclaw Bear
>   becomes a copy of that card and gains this ability.”

If the name were to be used literally, the text would read "*a creature you control not named Vigor*" instead of "*a creature you control other than Vigor*".

Comment: So, if two Vigors were in play they would infact only refer to themselves as objects and therefore protect each other?

Comment: @zo0x Yes. Rules text on a card mentioning the card name always refers to that card only. The template would have to be "other than a source named Vigor" for it not to be the case. See [Blazing Effigy](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=1560)

Comment: I guess in the context of **Vigor** the template would be *other than a creature named Vigor* — similar to the [Relentless Rats](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=205082) rules text.

Comment: Even if this weren't the case, Lazav always keeps the name "Lazav, Dimir Mastermind"